# Error, always return undefine value in my class

Tags: javascript

I Need help with my class in javascript, always obtain undefine value when size of vector is 2.

```
 function Inst_Mochila(){
  this.c_Inst_mochila = function(){
    var sizeInstancias = [];
    sizeInstancias.push(4);
    sizeInstancias.push(2);
    alert("--->2-->"+sizeInstancias.size);
  }
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size` doesn't exist. You are looking for `sizeInstancias.length`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length